# disabling checkbox in internet explorer with javascript and regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a dynamic booking page that enables a user to choose x amount of items to use on a course for a list of people.

An example: there may be 3 checkboxes listed for the course per person, but the limit is 2.  when 2 is reached the remaining 1 checkbox for that person is disabled.

The solution I currently have works perfectly in firefox and chrome, but not in Internet explorer.

To explain the reasoning for my code:

Because the person and course items are dynamic, in order to process the selection in php later, each checkbox has a dynamic name.

if each item has an id, and each person has an id
the checkbox name is based on [userid_itemid]

the check box names would follow a pattern like so for 3 checkboxes when 3 users are making their choices on a page
for user 1-(1_1), (1_2), (1_3)
for user 2-(2_1), (2_2), (2_3)
for user 3-(3_1), (3_2), (3_3)

Here is the code which enables the checkboxes to disable correctly in firefox and chrome:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var chktest="input\\["+$(this).attr('id');
        var bol = $("input[name^="+chktest+"_]:checked").length >= 2;
        $("input[name^="+chktest+"_]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
    });   
});
```

However Internet explorer (definitely in version 8) does not limit the checkboxes in any shape or form.

My code above was based upon this:

[Limit Checkbox amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966382/limit-checkbox-amount)  ANSWER 19 which shows a working demo.

It works cross browser in the demo provided there, but because of the nature of my data being dynamic, my code is more complex which i believe has derived the issue.

Comment: Can we at least see what you have please?

Comment: sorry, i was having an issue with parts of my question

Comment: I've re-tagged your question because you appear to be using jQuery (you don't mention) and you aren't using regex anywhere I can see. Feel free to make further corrections.

Comment: input[name^="+chktest+"_]  which means it would check 'input[1_' using the ^ regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

I wrote a [blog entry](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/06/helpful-jquery-selectors-select-by.html) a while back with some custom JQuery selectors I wrote over the years that I wanted to share. There is one in there for selecting by regex that you may find useful.

... at the very least it's a good starting point for how to write your own selector if you need to.  [Here's the code on github](https://github.com/blesh/jquery.lesh.selectors.js). The one that I think you'd use is `:attrregex`

**Option 2**

Outside of that, another option is to put custom attribute on your class for each aspect of what's in your names (presuming you have control over that):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_1-1" data-user="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="user_1-2" data-user="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="user_1-3" data-user="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="user_2-1" data-user="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="user_2-2" data-user="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="user_2-3" data-user="2"/>
```

then you could just select by `$('input[data-user=' + userId + ']')` or what have you.

I hope something in there helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Just tried option 2, but it still had same affect....works on firefox, but not Internet explorer..  var bol = $("input[data-id="+chktest+"]:checked").length >= <?= $course->booking_item_max; ?>;
   $("input[data-id="+chktest+"]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);