# Limit checked boxes to consecutive set in jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, limit

I want to do something like this: [Limit Checkbox amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966382/limit-checkbox-amount)

But with a little change. I want checkboxes to also have to be consecutive.

Little example:

If I have 10 checkboxes, and my limit is 3, then the user can check only first, second and third; or third, fourth, fifth. Not first, third, fourth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Revised code for consecutive check boxes.

```
$(function () {
    var mLimit = 3;
    $(':checkbox', 'div').click(function (e) {
        var c = 0;

        $(this)
            .parent()
            .find(':checkbox').each(function (i, el) {
                if (el.checked) c++;
                else c = 0;

                if (c > mLimit) e.preventDefault();
            });        
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sa2Lg/2/

---

For HTML like below,

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

You can limit using below script,

```
$(function () {
    $(':checkbox', 'div').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).parent().find(':checked').length > 3) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sa2Lg/

Comment: I've explain it badly... I mean not in a row, but consecutively... First, second, third or third, fourth, fifth, but not first, third, fifth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too lazy to really write it out for you because it hurts my head, but it can be accomplished using `nextAll()` and `prevAll()` functions.

If you do `$('input:checked').nextAll(':lt(2)');` you'll get the next two checkboxes from the checked one. That's how you'll have to check your inputs. I'm sure you can figure out the actual logic needed.