# Cant prevent user to select multiple checkboxes which data are retrieved from table(database)

Tags: php, javascript

I want to prevent user select more than 3 checkboxes but the data is retrieved from my table.

i.e. I have 5 checkboxes retrieved from my table but my script isnt work when user exceeds to the limit. Heres my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[id="fruits"]').click(function(event) {
if (this.checked && $('input:checked').length > 3) {
event.preventDefault();
alert('You\'re not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes');
}
});
</script>

<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT fruitId, fruitname, fruitDes  FROM tbl_fruit")) {
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th> <th>Name</th <th>Description</th> <th></th> </tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row->fruitId . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->fruitname ." </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->fruitDes ." </td>";
echo "<td><input type ='checkbox' name='fruits[]' value='" . $row->studId ."' id='fruits'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; } else {
echo "No results to display!";
}
}
else {
echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: If they select more than three, don't prevent further selections, it's much more user friendly to just give them a warning in the page. You only care that there are 3 that are checked when the form is submitted, let the user work out how to get there.

Comment: @RobG its part of my study sir, which later i could use this, maybe in other situation.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this, it might work ;)

[Limit Checkbox amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966382/limit-checkbox-amount)

Answer (score 0):

You're emitting the script before the inputs so the script doesn't find anything to bind to.  Wrap the contents of `<script>` in `$(function () { ... });` or move the script to *below* the input elements.

Answer (score 0):

put your script document readt function..

```
>     > $(document).ready(function() {
>     > $('input[id="fruits"]').click(function(event) { if (this.checked &&
>     > $('input:checked').length > 3) { event.preventDefault();
>     > alert('You\'re not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes'); } }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it, you need to first count how many are checked and if it's the maximum number, disable the unchecked ones. If the count is less than the number, enable all checkboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleCheckboxes(name, num) {

    var checkedCount = 0;
    var boxes = document.getElementsByName(name);
    var box, disable, i;

    // If there aren't enough boxes, forget it
    if (boxes.length < num) return;

    // Count how many are checked
    for (var i=0, iLen=boxes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      checkedCount += boxes[i].checked? 1 : 0;
    }

    // Work out if need to disable any
    disable = !!(checkedCount >= num); 

    // Only disable those that aren't checked
    // If fewer than num checked, enable them all
    for (i=0; i<iLen; i++) {
      box = boxes[i];
      box.disabled = box.checked? false : disable;
    }
}

// setTimeout is used so that if click comes from reset, the form is
// reset before listener runs
window.onload = function() {
  document.forms[0].onclick = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){toggleCheckboxes('fruits[]', 3)},10);
  }
}

</script>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple">Apple<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="orange">Orange<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="pear">Pear<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="cherry">Cherry<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="plum">Plum<br>
  <input type="reset"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: yes!!! sir thnks a lot, i really appreciate your help. now my work is working. whoa!! your so awesome sir.